# Generate a web application using maven generate

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have generated a project struture using maven using mvn archetype:generate and the project structure is as follows:
webapps
    -src
        -main
            -java 
              -com
                -web
                  -App.java
        -test

I have tried following the tutorial on the link [create web app](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)

Running mvn dependency:analyze-dep-mgt

but still the project structure differs.

While I use this 
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false,` I get Pom file missing

Where am I being wrong so that the struture differs and my web.xml not being generated?

```
C:\Users\user\workspace\webappspringapp\webapp>mvn dependency:analyze-dep-mgt
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.webapp:webapp:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\user\workspace\we
bappspringapp\webapp\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-cor
e:jar must be a valid version but is '${spring.version}'. @ line 14, column 13
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web
:jar must be a valid version but is '${spring.version}'. @ line 20, column 13
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web
mvc:jar must be a valid version but is '${spring.version}'. @ line 26, column 13

[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
```

Pom.xml part

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Comment: try the analyze tools from the dependency-plugin

especially the mvn dependency:analyze-dep-mgt

Comment: Did you replaced mvn `{project-packaging}` and `{project-name}` by your names?

Comment: What is the ouput (generated by mvn)? Where does the structure differ?

Comment: Yea they were replaced before being run

Comment: The structure differs from the link specified in the tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/. From the tutorial we have    |---main
   |-----resources
   |-----webapp
   |-------index.jsp
   |-------WEB-INF
   |---------web.xml but the struture generated for me does not contain the folder WEB-INF and web.xml

Comment: I got it myself. Maven has different template files to generate diffrent folder structures

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

This is used to view the dependency hierarchy of the project currently being built. It will output the resolved tree of dependencies that the Maven build process actually uses.

Comment: I have tried it gives me some errors on versions. Errors logged in my questiona above